# Convert number of days to date in excel using ReoGridControl for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm having an excel sheet (Excel 2007). I have used ReoGridControl in it. When I'm opening the sheet, the default date format is getting changed and instead of date, the number of days is being displayed.

I tried using

```
worksheet.SetRangeDataFormat(RangePosition.EntireRange,CellDataFormatFlag.DateTime);
```

but it is converting other fields which are not dates into date format.

Is there any other way to convert the specific column to the date format or the way to get the data format of the particular column?

This is the original file.

[image]

After loading the file, I'm getting

[image]

After applying **SetRangeDataFormat** I'm getting

[image]

Comment: So, you're just concerned that it's also adjusting Column C, but Column D is correct and what you expect - correct?

Comment: I just expect column D to be corrected. All other columns should remain as it is @gravity

Comment: OK, that's what I thought.  Can you provide where you're setting `RangePosition` `Range` at?  It seems like you need to adjust that `Range` after applying the data, but BEFORE you change `DataFormat`

Comment: Actually RangePosition is not fixed date column may differ in excel sheet so we can not set any fixed range here.

Comment: You're sending a `RangePosition.EntireRange` which is a `Range` in Excel.  That is your issue.  You need to isolate to the specific column instead, and only set that `DataFormat` to Column D.

Comment: The problem here is, we don't know exactly which column will contain the date field. We are just extracting a file from a source and the file can have the multiple numbers of date columns, as well as the position of the column, can be anywhere. It would also be great if we can find the data format of each field so that we can perform the necessary operation on the specified column. @gravity